# Android exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' - not due to the SD card

Tags: android

I am having a problem copying files (.so binaries) from my assets directory to the app installation "/data/data/name.ofmy.app/lib" directory.

When I try to I get the following error:

> 07-09 11:00:48.902: W/System.err(25122): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/name.ofmy.app/lib/libOlsrdPudWireFormat.so: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

This happens when the following code is being ececuted:

```
if ((so = new File(dir, fileName)).exists()) {
    /*
     * Check to see if this timestamp pre-dates the current package
     */
    if ((pkg = new File(ctx.getPackageResourcePath())).exists()) {
        if (pkg.lastModified() < so.lastModified()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "extractFile: File up to date");
            return;
        }
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "extractFile: library present but out of date");
    so.delete();
}
Log.v(TAG, "extractFile: copying library");
InputStream in = ctx.getAssets().open(name);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(so);
```

It breaks right at `InputStream in = ctx.getAssets().open(name);` when there is not an already existing file with that name...

I have been reading similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but unfortunately that did not help. Most are copying to the SD card, but I am not.

Also the strange part is that a previous directory (/bin instead of /lib), which is also supplied within my assets, does get copied without any problem in the same /dat/data... directory!

I tried adding the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission to no avail.

I even tried adding `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` just before I try to copy anything, also to no avail.

It's a rooted phone BTW!

I also double checked if the file is really there in the assets, and it is!

Comment: moved this comment as being an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of trying I changed the directory name from `lib` to `libs` (because as mentioned in my question, I also copied another directory named `/bin` without any issues) and guess what: now it works!

**It seems you cannot use the `/lib` directoryname whilst copying. I have no idea why, though.**

Comment: Using android I have occasionally been able to use dd instead of cp where cp wouldn't work. A longshot but could do what you need

Comment: thats a good tip, but in my specific case I am copying using filestreams not using the linux commands !!!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you forgot to put in the manifest:

```
<manifest 
    .
    . 
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```